# How to convert into JsonObject and bind it into Model Class in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization

I have a model class:

```
public class AccountDetails
{

    public string MainCode { get; set; }

    public string BranchCode { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
}
```

I have a data that i retrieved from API :

```
[{'MainCode':'0030004875281','BranchCode':'003','Name':'BIMAL KUMAR ADHIKARI','MobileNo':'9845685475'}]
```

Now I need to bind the data into model. As i have tried parsing it into JArray and Deserialize it yet no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data from API is array with one element, so you need to bind it to array of your models.
Using `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```
var data = "[{'MainCode':'0030004875281','BranchCode':'003','Name':'BIMAL KUMAR ADHIKARI','MobileNo':'9845685475'}]";
var models = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AccountDetails>>(data);
```